# Split a string but retain first delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in the form `"/A/B/C/D"`. Is there a regex or a simple way to capture this into a String array of the form `[/A, B, C, D]`? Essentially, split on "/" but retain the first instance of the delimiter? I can be guaranteed that the input string will have "/" as the first character and at least one "/" following the first. My attempt has been this so far:

```
private String[] customSplit(String input) {
    if (!input.startsWith("/")) {
        input = "/" + input;
    }

    String[] output = input.split("/");
    output[1] = "/" + output[1];
    return output;
}
```

The above is a bit clunky though (and has an empty "" spot at index 0)  so any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead in split to avoid split on first delimiter:

```
String[] toks = "/A/B/C/D".split("(?!^)/");
//=> [/A, B, C, D]
```

Here `(?!^)` is a negative lookahead that will skip start position for delimiter  `/`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEALOK/8)

Comment: any edge cases to consider for this solution?

Answer (score 0):

A dirty solution..but at least should work.
It assumes that you have at least 2 elements in the string, otherwise you've to add some error handling code, but from what you've written it should always be like that.

```
private String[] customSplit(String input) {
    String preparedInput=input;
    if (input.startsWith("/")) {
        preparedInput=input.substring(1);
    }

    String[] output = preparedInput.split("/");
    output[0] = "/" + output[0];
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
private String[] customSplit(String input) {
    String[] output = input.substring(1).split("/");
    output[0] = "/" + output[0];
    return output;
}
```